# Nothing is being saved after I logout each time

Tags: usb, webapps

I just downloaded the Ubuntu 14.04 version of Linux and I feel really dumb.  I am booting from a usb. Every time I shut my computer down it doesn't save anything that I had downloaded or any of my settings.  Every time I log out I try to log back in but I don't know what my username or password is.   Please help

Comment: How did you create the bootable USB?  Did you create a persistent storage area and what size is that area?

Comment: I created it using Unetbootin.  How can I tell if I created a persistent storage area and how big it is??

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu right now as well just so ya know

Answer (score 0):

When creating a bootable USB in unetbootin, you have the option of specifying some space for persistence.

[image]

Specifying a value here will allow Ubuntu to save settings, data, applications, other personalizations so that the next time you use the USB to boot, you will have data from your previous session still available.

Comment: Ok.. So I have tried doing that again by resetting those settings to like 100 MB but it still has not saved.  What should the settings be?? Do I need to download the iso file again and put it in??

Comment: Also my  usb stick is 12 GB so how many MB would you recommend??